# Google maps plot route between multiple points

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to  draw the shortest driving route between one pick up point to multiple drop-off points. Like this:

[image: sample image displaying intended result]

Comment: Use the directions service, with multiple waypoints.

Comment: possible related question: [Use one waypoint as destination in Gmaps Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858089/use-one-waypoint-as-destination-in-gmaps-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can use;

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/
```

Each `\` is a koordinates which can be include;

- Lang,lat *39.941577,32.8005281*
- Place name *Ankara*

And here is a example:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/39.941577,32.8005281/39.9676012,32.7301712/39.9248845,32.7076527/
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Ankara/İstanbul/İzmir/
```