# Get routes from google Direction API with origin and waypoints but no destination

Tags: google-maps, shortest-path

I want to use Google Direction API with only origin and waypoints to get the shortest path without destination point. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you can not, destination is a required parameter in all Directions API requests, but you can do a request without waypoints.

If you want the shortest path you just need to iterate through the response to get it.

here is an example how to do it: https://jsbin.com/nihihis/1/edit?html,js,output

in this I iterate the response and show the shortest path as green and the longest as red.

```
 var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: "DRIVING",
        provideRouteAlternatives: true
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        console.log('init');
        console.log('status ' + status);
        if (status == 'OK') {

            console.log('results', response.routes);
            //
            var routesSteps = [];
            var routes = response.routes;
            var colors = ['red', 'black', 'green'];

            for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

              if(i==0) {
                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                    polylineOptions: {

                        strokeColor: colors[2],
                        strokeWeight: 4,
                        strokeOpacity: .3
                    }
                });
              } else if(i== routes.length - 1) {
                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                    polylineOptions: {

                        strokeColor: colors[0],
                        strokeWeight: 4,
                        strokeOpacity: .3
                    }
                });
              } else {
                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                    polylineOptions: {

                        strokeColor: colors[1],
                        strokeWeight: 4,
                        strokeOpacity: .3
                    }
                });
              }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use one waypoint as destination in Gmaps Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858089/use-one-waypoint-as-destination-in-gmaps-api)